# difficult set and get in combined properties

Tags: c#, properties

I would combine the two properties FirstName and LastName and FullName properties to create
But they do not know what to write in the set.

```
 public class Customer : CommonEntity
{


    public String FirstName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public String LastName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }



    public string FullName
    {
        get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
        set { **.....** }

    }


}
```

Thank you

Comment: FullName should ideally be a ReadOnly property

Comment: does it need a setter, or is this for display only?

Comment: I need a setter because in method to serialize and deserialize these properties should be used

Comment: You could use {FirstName = value.Split(' ')[0]; LastName = value.Split(' ')[1];} but that would not be very robust...

Comment: Why don't you just serialize and deserialize the `FirstName` and `LastName` properties? The value of `FullName` can be fully determined based on those. Saving all three property values should, in most scenarios, not be done, as it creates a redundancy that will create more problems than it will solve. What will happen if for some reason the deserialized values do not fit together any more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deriving the first and last name from a full name is extremely difficult. Think of 'John Charles Lee', 'Pedro de la Cruz', 'Pieter van den Hoogenband', etc.

If you use serialization, do not serialize the `FullName` property. Most serializers do not do anything with `get` only properties.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I would like to add a name like "John Charles Lee" - which would be an example where splitting at the first whitespace does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need it for (de)serialization you need the property to have a setter. However, you don't actually need to *do* anything in the setter. We have classes we use for outputting data to xml which is purely just a readonly property. We got around this by making the setter empty but present. The Serialization routine quite happily accepts this and spits it out to the xml file.

```
public string FullName
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName, this.LastName); }
    set { //Do Nothing }
}
```

It's not ideal, as it looks like a writeable property. But you could use XmlComments to indicate that it is read only. It's fine for our purposes as our classes are designed purely for writes to Xml.

Alternatively, could you just exclude FullName from the Serialization process since it's always just a composite of the other two? So long as they are present you can always retrieve the FullName anyway.